# usage of RandomAccessFile to rewrite the contents

Tags: android, file, random-access

I am getting error in RandomAccessFile as, change type files to file. What do I need to do?

```
File[] files = root.listFiles(); 
for ( File f : files )  
{ 
if (f.isDirectory()) 
continue; 
FileChannel rwChannel = new RandomAccessFile(files, "rw").getChannel();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(files, "rw");
randomAccessFile.write("yourstring".getBytes());
randomAccessFile.close();
```

you do not need to get the `FileChannel` associated with  `RandomAccessFile`. You can use directly the `randomAccessFile` object

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for RandomAccessFile takes a single File object, not a File[], which is what you are attempting to do. Just change the parameter "files" to "f"...

Refer to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

RandomAccessFile(File file, String mode)
          Creates a random access file stream to read from, and optionally to write to, the file specified by the File argument.